# fetch data from jSON file

Tags: jquery, json

Hi friend I'm learing hoq jSON works I create file named `demo_ajax_json.js` which has following code

```
[
{ 
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 25
},
{ 
  "firstName": "SAM",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 36
},
{ 
  "firstName": "MAX",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 55
}
]
```

I'm tryiung to fetch `firstName` and `age` only. I wrote following code

```
function json(){
$.getJSON( "demo_ajax_json.js", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( firstName, age) {
    $("div ul").append( "<li id='" + firstName + "'>" + age+ "</li>" );
    });

});
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){

      json();
  });
});
```

And this code giving me this

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

Plz help guys how to get this done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
...        
var items = [];
$.each( data, function(index, value) {
  $("div ul").append( "<li id='" + value.firstName + "'>" + value.age+ "</li>" );
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be this:

```
function json(){
  $.getJSON( "demo_ajax_json.js", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function(i,obj) {
    $("div ul").append( "<li id='" + obj.firstName + "'>" + obj.age+ "</li>" );
    });

  });
}
```

Comment: What's `var items = [];` for?

Comment: @GaryLuck this is used by OP. that's why I have remain it as it is.

Comment: Whoops! Thought I was commenting on OP. (Am on mobile) Though now that I look, OP is also not using It for anything. Does it need to be there?

Comment: @GaryLuck May be or may be not. depend on OP requirement.